# What abilities/vigors can I find?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

What "powerups" or vigors are available to the user? Are there secret ones I can find?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted so much?

Comment: Maybe because he didn't check the in-game menu that lists the vigors

Comment: I think it's a fair question. Not the _most_ useful, perhaps, but the possibility of secret unlisted vigors is plausible. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Possesion](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Possession)
- [Devil's Kiss](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Devil%27s_Kiss)
- [Murder of Crows](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Murder_of_Crows)
- [Shock Jockey](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Shock_Jockey)
- [Bucking Bronco](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Bucking_Bronco)
- [Undertow](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Undertow)
- [Charge](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Charge)
- [Return to Sender](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Return_to_Sender)

There are currently no known "secret" vigors.